# Applying style input-sm to bootstrap-select plugin completely changes control's appearance

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, select, plugins

I'm developing a website using Bootstrap and Laravel and so far, things are looking pretty alright. However, I've started using the bootstrap-select plugin found here and stumbled upon an annoying bug:

http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

In the document.ready function, I have the following code to reduce the height of the control a little:

```
$("#myControl").selectpicker(
{style: "input-sm"});
```

Somehow, this completely changes the look and feel of the select box. Instead of having the control be white with a light-gray border (as you see on the website), the entire control turns dark gray with no border at all (or the border's still there and it blends with the control's background).

Did anybody ever get this bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks Ted, thanks to you I was able to figure out what I did wrong. You were right, I was using the wrong style. However, there was an additional quirk needed for things to work properly:

```
$("#myControl").selectpicker({
    style: "btn-default btn-sm"
});
```

So yeah, btn-default for the desired appearance and btn-sm for the desired size. Combine these two together and things will work out perfectly.

Thanks :)

Comment: i tried `<select class="form-control selectpicker btn-sm" id="fmodel">` but it doesn't work

Comment: @sanojlawrence I don't know if that's the problem, but if you look closely, you'll notice I also add the class 'btn-default' to my control. Maybe that's what's missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you right click and view page source, this is not just a simple select.
I used something like this from the internet

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm">                                       
<select class="form-control selectpicker" id="aaaaaa" data-live-search="true">
<option value="1">x1</option>
<option value="2">x2</option>
<option value="3">x3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Notice the `form-group-sm` in the form group instead of `input-sm` in the form control.

Answer (score 0):

The selectpicker plugin uses a bootstrap button to create the dropdown, not a select, so use the appropriate button style, like `btn-sm`:

```
$("#myControl").selectpicker({
    style: "btn-sm"
});
```